# Negate the current Mask using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am new to QGIS.  I wanted to negate (behaving like NOT gate in a digital circuit) the MASK I have obtained earlier. That means I want to convert all 0s to  1 and all 1s to 0s. Is there any way to do it using raster calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following expression in the raster calculator:

```
(("LayerName@1" = 0) AND (("LayerName@1" = 1) - 1))
```

Example, The input Test data has a pixel values of 0 and 1.

[image]

Running the above equation as follows:

```
(("Test@1" = 0) AND (("Test@1" = 1) - 1))
```

It produced the following result:

[image]